# How do Skrulls create clothing?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

As mentioned in *Captain Marvel* and [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97677/why-cant-skrulls-heal), Skrulls have the ability to copy anyone's DNA structure and replicate it in their bodies. In the movie we see that they replicate clothing as well. Given that the way Skrulls "copy" someone is through their DNA, it should be impossible to replicate their clothing and other non-biological items.

Is there any explanation to why or how they can do this?

Comment: When you say "as mentioned here" you are actually referring to your very own question. Do you have anyone *else* to back you on the premise that the Skrulls' replication actually works on DNA to begin with?

Comment: The movie said that they can copy someone down to the level of copying their DNA.  It does not say the copying is *just* about their DNA.

Comment: Still how can anyone produce clothes of any fibre out of organic substances? I think artists took cinematic liberty here and didn't think much

Comment: They actually ask him if he could turn in to a file cabinet. His reaction was "Why would I want to do that?" which, to me, implies that *he could* change to inorganic substance if he *wanted to*.

Comment: Seeing as how they can copy DNA just by looking at someone from hundreds of feet away, I don't think clothing is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie does not go in full details to what are the Skrulls powers, but here we have a full explanation on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skrull):

> Skrulls are green-skinned reptilian humanoids with large pointed ears, red or green eyes, and chins with several vertical folds in the skin below their mouths. The males are mostly bald, while the females have full black hair. Skrulls are known for genetic and molecular instability, and genetic diversity, due to Celestial experimentation creating the Skrull "Deviants". The Skrulls are known for their physical malleability and ability to shapeshift to any size, shape, or color at will, taking on the appearance but not the characteristics of other beings and objects. Skrulls are able to assume virtually any form, be it organic (e.g., cows [10]) or inorganic (e.g., lamp [40]). As a result, the Skrulls excel at spying and infiltration. Skrulls are also able to use their shapeshifting abilities to form weapons (e.g., blades and clubs) with parts of their bodies, making them dangerous hand-to-hand combatants. Their sexual dimorphism is roughly the same of a human being, but their sexual orientation is more complex since they can change their genders at will.

Answer (score 0):

#### Skrulls use a device to create clothing

Skrulls use a special device that can "absorb" their original clothing and then generate the clothing of the person they are impersonating. The usage of the device is visible in the clip below from *Captain Marvel*. In the clip, you can see a purple glow on Talos’ left shoulder (on the right side of the screen) that indicates the device is working. Notice that at first, it "absorbs" his Skrull clothing, leaving him bare for a moment, and then it creates a new one based on the person he is replicating.

[image: GIF of the scene I described above]