# Why do Skrulls' clothing not return to their original form when they die?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, secret-invasion

How come when a Skrull dies, they change back to their natural form but their clothing does not?

In *Captain Marvel*, when Fury crashes the car, a Skrull dies and changes back to their original form, but the clothing remains the same.

Comment: Related: [How do Skrulls create clothing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97681/27264)

Comment: To avoid 'Eww' of the audience?

Comment: I don't have or remember the source of this so I won't submit as an answer, but I think it's because their body is related to their sense of "self" and so their mind reverts it as they die. Their clothing is generally not related to it.

I expect that's writers making up for simple mistakes though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Skrulls’ clothes don’t transform when they die because their clothes are not part of their bodies.

When a Skrull dies, their body reverts to its natural form, but their clothing remains the same as the last form they took. Aside from *Captain Marvel*, this is also consistent with what we see in *Secret Invasion*, where several Skrulls die and keep the clothing they were wearing.

Skrulls use a special device that can "absorb" their original clothing and then generate the outfit of the person they are impersonating. The usage of the device is visible in the clip below from *Captain Marvel*:

[image: GIF of the scene I described below]

In the clip, you can see a purple glow on Talos’ left shoulder (on the right side of the screen) that indicates the device is working. Notice that at first, it "absorbs" his Skrull clothing, leaving him bare briefly, and then it creates a new one based on the person he is replicating.